# Loading into RAM & Executing machine code stored in an object file

Tags: linux, object, arm, execute, mmap

I have built a JIT , which reads c codes and converts them to an object file ( .o )  ; the object file stores a ````main(int argc, char **argv)'''' function . my question is how may I load this object into memory and execute the main function stored in it ?

NOTE : I've seen many similar questions in SO but I could'nt find my answer so please do not mark this question as a duplicated question

Comment: What format does your object file have? Or is it containing pure executable code without additional information?

Comment: @Armali The same format as GCC's output .o objects (I 'm using GCC)

Answer (score 0):

You could direct `gcc` to generate a shared object (.so) file (this is possible from the .c file as well as from the .o file) - options `-shared` and `-fpic` may be required for this. Then you can load it with `void *handle = dlopen(...)`, get the address of the contained function with `p = dlsym(handle, "main")` and execute it with `p()`.

Comment: I have no linker. Would it be possible to create `.so` without linker?

Comment: Hm - to do this, one would have to write at least parts of a linker. But I wonder ... if you have no linker, how do you generate the program that is supposed to load the other object and execute it? Don't you use libraries? Where do the functions for the file operations etc. come from and how do they get into your program?

Comment: All needed functions and libraries are previously loaded into RAM by the executable which is supposed to run that object

Comment: You didn't answer the question how you generate _that_ executable. And how are these functions and libraries different from the object file of your question? Since you are already able to load the former, what is the precise problem with loading the latter?

Comment: Let me explain better; I have a working GCC and a not-working linker. so I decided to load the object file by a program and run a function inside that.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question how you generate what in your last comment you name _a program_. Now I'll guess: You generate _that program_ on another machine. - I'm afraid the best approach to solving the problem is getting the linker to work.